# Can't access My Profile on Careers 2.0

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I just got an invitation to Careers 2.0 and I accepted the invitation sent to my email. While filling the email information on the site, when I typed my SO email (which is the same address that got me invited to Careers), the system said that an account was already registered with that email address and that I should logout/login to continue.

After login in with my SO open id (which uses the very same email address), whenever I click [my profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv) firefox says: **Problem loading page**.

```
The page isn't redirecting properly    
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
```

I'm successfully logged in but I can't create a profile. Also, the invitation I received via email does not work anymore. What do I do?

**EDIT**:

I'm currently logged in, just clicked on **my profile** tab. The page says:

```
Get Started with your Stack Overflow Profile

Thanks for accepting our invitation!

Let’s double-check the basics...
```

If I type in my full name, email and location and click on `continue to my profile..` button. A red label shows up saying: **Hmm, that email already exists on another account. You will need to log out of your existing account and log back in.**

Then I log out and repeat the whole process again, and again, and again, ...

Comment: Using Firefox 3.6.13 (Ubuntu Linux).

Comment: I've got the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!  We hadn't accounted for someone accepting an invite, but then leaving the page before creating their profile.  Now we send you to the "Create a profile" page correctly in that case.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment.  I use 2 different OpenIds across the exchange and when I logged in with my other OpenId it worked.  Someone may want to take a look at that process though as it appears I now have 2 different accounts on Careers.SE.