# Also can't access My Profile on Careers 2.0

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I seem to be suffering from the exact same problem reported in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81704/cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-0).  The answer and subsequent comments there seem to suggest someone on the admin side needs to do something to clear the issue for me.

Can someone oblige please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that.  It should be fixed now.  Can you try again?

Comment: That's better.  Into profile now thanks.

Comment: @timday: No problem. Thanks for accepting an invite!