# My careers profile disappeared

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I think [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83064/also-cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-0) (or similar) happened to me.

I received an email telling me I had been granted some invitations, and now my profile on careers is gone. When I click the My Profile thing at the top, it tells me that I can sign up for one.

Then I tried to use my invites to invite myself back :p, and it goes to a 404-ish page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that notJim.  We had a duplicate account for you that I just merged into your main account.  Take another stab and let me know if things are OK.