# My careers.stackoverflow.com profile disappeared

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

(As also seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90807/my-careers-profile-disappeared) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83064/also-cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-0).) I recently went to log in because I received a notification that I had an email from a company. The email link from careers.stackoverflow.com was a 404 error after I logged in, and I couldn't find my profile anymore ("My Profile" goes to a page saying "Get a Careers 2.0 profile!"). User #240443, email stackoverflow@davidrobins.net.

Could someone please restore my profile (and messages)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two accounts. I've merged them, so you should be all set.