# Can't accept Careers 2.0 invitation

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I have the same problem that was described [in this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81704/cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-0) and [in this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83064/also-cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-0) questions.

I received invitation to create Careers 2.0 profile, accepted it and was forwarded to "My Profile" page. Then I tried to fill in my details, received a strange error message:

> Hmm, that email already exists on another account. You will need to log out of your existing account and log back in.

In the  original questions I am referring to the problem was solved manually by the administrators. Can someone please fix this problem for me too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed - you should be good to go.

Comment: Now there is another error. The page says all the relevant info was sent to you, so ...

Comment: Hmm - there was an error getting some data from SO but we were not able to reproduce and your profile looks ok. Could you try once more (and if it happens again let me know what you were doing when it errored)?

Comment: The exact same thing happened to me. I recieved my invitation today and I can't use it. Should I ask it as a question again?

Comment: @stribika Nope, no need. You're all set.

Comment: @stribika No problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Would you mind taking a look at my account as well? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mirko Froehlich you should be all set now

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thanks, @Korneel.

Comment: Same for me too - any chance you could fix mine up? Thanks

Comment: @paul, you should be all set. @all, to not keep adding on comments, if you have the same problem, please email careers@stackoverflow.com. Thanks!

Comment: same issue for me

Comment: @Gabriel You should be all set

Comment: Might as well keep this thread going and point out that I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @dan - your accounts have been merged