# Problems with SO Careers 2.0 Invitation. Email already exists on another account?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I am experiencing the same problems as described in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83527/cant-accept-careers-2-0-invitation) question (and the same as described in the questions that question links to): I received an invitation to create a profile on StackOverflow Careers 2.0, but after filling in all the details, I got the following error message:

> Hmm, that email already exists on
>   another account. You will need to log
>   out of your existing account and log
>   back in.

In the aforementioned questions the problems were solved manually by an administrator. Is it possible someone fixes this for me as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi - you should be all set now. Can you please log back in and try to complete your profile?

Comment: Great - glad to hear!

Comment: I'm also having the same problem — can you fix me up?

Comment: @david: fixed! @all: pls email careers@stackoverflow.com if you have the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Korneel Bouman: I've got the same thing happening to me.

Comment: @Anderson Imes: should be fixed (you had two accounts)