# Cannot add location/email to careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, email, location

I cannot seem to add my location or email. This is a copy of the log from chrome. I've removed my email address. Hopefully this should be of some use.

Cheers
Tony

```
Request URL:http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/update
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:220
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:__qca=P0-370968408-1294648383004; o=1; superSecretTrackingCookie=61101030-8007-4a1a-a4f2-da20e2be2105; __utmz=140029553.1300963922.298.343.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=mvc%20wcf%20authorize%20filter; usr=t=srp8MtWS3EKV&s=Wmx3WQIZzUWt; __utma=140029553.478010050.1294648383.1300956005.1300962591.298; __utmc=140029553; __utmb=140029553.23.10.1300962591; __utmz=244929559.1300965715.6.5.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/tagged/c%23; csouser=t=m80e42pA3kGt&s=zhN2nvyB9Uf7; __utmv=; __utma=244929559.1644349576.1296044345.1299001749.1300965715.6; __utmc=244929559; __utmb=244929559.10.10.1300965715; _chartbeat2=d4x9qrdma5sfkvw7
Host:careers.stackoverflow.com
Origin:http://careers.stackoverflow.com
Referer:http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/editinline/5868
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.151 Safari/534.16
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Data
RealName:Tony Williams
Email:**REMOVED***
DisplayGravatar:true
DisplayGravatar:false
Location:Hartlepool, England, United Kingdom
WebsiteUrl:http://tonywilliams.me.uk
formname:Personal
save:save
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:60
Cache-Control:private
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:158
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 24 Mar 2011 11:31:28 GMT
Location:/error?aspxerrorpath=/cv/update
Server:nginx
```

Comment: Looking into this now.

Comment: Champion - All working fine now

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you were suffering from [this problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84010/problems-with-so-careers-2-0-invitation-email-already-exists-on-another-account).  Please try it again.