# Problems with SO Careers 2.0 Invitation. Email already exists on another account? (Repost)

Tags: support, jobs

Copying & pasting from a previous question:

I am experiencing the same problems as described in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83527/cant-accept-careers-2-0-invitation) question (and the same as described in the questions that question links to): I received an invitation to create a profile on StackOverflow Careers 2.0, but after filling in all the details, I got the following error message:

```
Hmm, that email already exists on another account. You will need to log out of your existing account and log back in.
```

In the aforementioned questions the problems were solved manually by an administrator. Is it possible someone fixes this for me as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup... same issue. You should be all set.