# Can't access My Profile on Careers 2.0 after invitation

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I seem to have the exact same issue as in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81704/cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-0) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83064/also-cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-0). The answer and subsequent comments there seem to suggest someone on the admin side needs to do something to clear the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that.  Should be good to go now.