# Careers 2.0 invitation profile creation error

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs, invitation

I received a Careers 2.0 invitation, and am keen to try it out, but the initial account creation page fails with:

> Hmm, that email already exists on
>   another account. You will need to log
>   out of your existing account and log
>   back in.

I tried logging out and back in (using Google OpenId), but to no apparent avail. Any ideas?

Related questions:

- [Can't access My Profile on Careers 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81704/cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-0)
- [Also can't access My Profile on Careers 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83064/also-cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-)
- [Can't accept Careers 2.0 invitation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83527/cant-accept-careers-2-0-invitation)
- [Can't access My Profile on Careers 2.0 after invitation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83595/cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-0-after-invitation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that.  You should be good to go now.

Comment: Thanks, appears to be working now!