# Careers invitation acceptance problem

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I'm having the same problem with the careers invitation as [this support request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83595/cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-0-after-invitation).

> Hmm, that email already exists on another account. You will need to log out of your existing account and log back in.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about that. Take another crack at it and let me know if it's working.