# Can't set up my Careers 2 profile

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

Hi, I'm having the same issue this person had.

[Can't access My Profile on Careers 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81704/cant-access-my-profile-on-careers-2-0)

I started to set my profile up then walked away from it and only came back to it today. If an admin could please fix this, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try again now?  Let me know if things are still screwy so I can register myself for this week's Beating of the Employees.

Comment: It is working now, and I am currently filling out my account. Thanks so much!

Comment: Whew...looks like I might get through this week beating free... *oh please oh please oh please oh please...*

Comment: the week is young! (;